# wpf break Window.Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworks

i use FrameWork 4.5.
"Window.Child is Grid".
my problem is starting when i want to scale window, or stretch.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMHpy.jpg

however when i stretch a little bit more or less its rapair itself.
i have another problem. with the same couse.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WPjv.jpg

this black strip can show and hide when i stretch window.
i try to do

```
Grid.InvalidateVisual();
Button.InvaldidateVisual();
Grid.InvalidateVisual();
```

by the event Button1_Click.
But it did not change anything

Comment: What??? Please post the relevant XAML and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually looks like a graphics driver bug.  WPF, by default, relies on the hardware acceleration of your graphics card in order to render.

The tearing is a common sign that there is a bug in your graphics card/driver.  You can [change the rendering settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx) used by WPF to disable hardware acceleration, which will likely correct the tearing issues.